# "would" or "would have" in a conditional sentence

Tags: usage, conditional-constructions

Is the following sentence correct?

> If your jogging clothes were not made of permeable fabric you would drown in your sweat.

I think it should be

> If your jogging clothes were not made of permeable fabric you would have drowned in your sweat.

Because the action didn't happen

Comment: Both are correct. It depends on when the drowning might have taken place.The original sentence can be understood to mean "... you would [now be] drowning ..." or "... you would drown [once you started jogging] ...". Your version is what would have happened in the past.and could possibly be worded "If your jogging clothes _had not been_ made ..."

Comment: While both sentences are fine, the original sounds a lot better to me. (As a general statement). But if you want to express what you have in the second sentence, it would be better to say: *If your jogging clothes **had not been** made of permeable fabric, you would have drowned in your sweat.*

Comment: How is the title of the question related to anything being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. It depends on when the drowning might have taken place. The original sentence can be understood to mean "... you would [now be] drowning ..." or "... you would drown [once you started jogging] ...". Your version is what would have happened in the past, and could possibly be worded "If your jogging clothes had not been made ..."

While both sentences are fine, the original sounds a lot better to me. (As a general statement). But if you want to express what you have in the second sentence, it would be better to say

> If your jogging clothes *had not been* made of permeable fabric, you would have drowned in your sweat.